# Как добавить несколько чекбоксов в таблицу QTableWidget через цикл?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qtablewidget, qcheckbox

Это не весь код программы, но остальной код на ходовую не влияет. 
В таблицу `QTableWidget` выводится только один чекбокс, но планировалось выводить в каждую строку по `QCheckBox`.

---

```
...
    self.checkBoxes = []
    self.CheckBox = QCheckBox()

    def readFile(self):
        # считаем количество строк
        with open(os.getcwd() + '/config.txt', 'r') as f:
            i = 0
            for __ in f:
                i = i + 1
                self.countRows = i

        # считаем количество колонок и подготавливаем массив
        with open(os.getcwd() + '/config.txt', 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
            text = text.replace('\n', '')
            text = text.split('|')
            self.text = text[:-1]
            print(self.text)
            self.countCols = int(len(text) / self.countRows)
            self.arr = np.array(text)
            self.arr.shape = (self.countRows, self.countCols)

        self.tblMo = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tblMo.setGeometry(10, 30, 680, 190)
        self.tblMo.setColumnCount(self.countCols + 1)
        self.tblMo.setRowCount(self.countRows)
        for i in range(int(self.countRows)):
            for j in range(int(self.countCols)):
                self.tblMo.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(self.arr[i][j]))
        
        for i in range(int(self.countRows)):
            self.checkBoxes.append(self.CheckBox)

        print(self.checkBoxes)
        # тот самый не рабочий цикл
        for i in range(int(self.countRows)):
            self.tblMo.setCellWidget(i, self.countCols, self.checkBoxes[i])
...
```

Comment: В `self.checkBoxes` добавляете один и тот же виджет, поэтому и в setCellWidget передается один и тот же виджет. Попробуйте сделать копии, например не `self.checkBoxes.append(self.CheckBox)`, а `self.checkBoxes.append(QCheckBox())`

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QTableWidget(rows, columns, self)

        for row in range(rows):
            widget   = QWidget()
            checkbox = QCheckBox()
            checkbox.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            layoutH = QHBoxLayout(widget)
            layoutH.addWidget(checkbox)
            layoutH.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            layoutH.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 0, widget)
            self.table.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(row)))

        self.button = QPushButton("Контроль выбранных QCheckBox ")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.ButtonClicked)

        layoutV     = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.table)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.button)


    def ButtonClicked(self):
        checked_list = []
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            if self.table.cellWidget(i, 0).findChild(type(QCheckBox())).isChecked():
                checked_list.append(self.table.item(i, 1).text())
        print(checked_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(3, 2)
    window.resize(350, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можно ли осуществить данную операцию через QtDesigner? Что если нужно будет скажем создать несколько `CheckBox` с подписями `QLabel` в одной ячейке?

Comment: @AddmiX задайте новый вопрос. Приложите ваш пример и расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.